# Android - Google Maps with Photos

Tags: android, image, android-camera, gallery

I'm currently working on a Camera app. The app lets you, obviously, take a picture however, we have a feature that the photos you taken using the app can be shown on a map where it was taken. [Like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyDAz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using custom marker, [See this](http://www.nasc.fr/android/android-using-layout-as-custom-marker-on-google-map-api/)